# python-how to print a list in the same row

Tags: python, list, printing

Hi How can I print my list L and K

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5] 
K=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,9]]
```

As:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

and

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
4 -> 5 -> 6 
5 -> 9
```

Comment: If you're using python >= 3.5 , use @wim answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` accepts a separator, available as a keyword-only argument:

```
>>> print(*L, sep=' -> ')
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

Same idea for the other one:

```
>>> for L in K:
...     print(*L, sep=' -> ')
...     
1 -> 2 -> 3
4 -> 5 -> 6
5 -> 9
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about it! even pycharm got confused https://screenpresso.com/=lDcwg

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question, but:

```
>>> L=[1,2,3,4,5] 
>>> K=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,9]]
>>> 
>>> print " -> ".join([str(i) for i in L])
'1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5'
>>> for L in K:
...   print " -> ".join([str(i) for i in L])
... 
1 -> 2 -> 3
4 -> 5 -> 6
5 -> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a function:

```
def printer(mylist):
    for n in mylist[:-1]:
        print n, '->',
    print mylist[-1]
```

Then using the function you should have your required output from:

```
printer(K)
#>>> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

and

```
for o in L: printer(o)
#>>> 1 -> 2 -> 3
#>>> 4 -> 5 -> 6
#>>> 5 -> 9
```